# LWJGL Applet crashes when opening file

Tags: permissions, jar, applet, lwjgl, jar-signing

I'm making a java application using LWJGL. When exporting the project into jar and signing it,  it crashes when I'm trying to open a file like this:

```
    File file;
    try {
        file = new File(getClass().getResource(map_filename).toURI());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

You can check the applet here:
http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~vladis2/LD23.html
it crushes right after you click the play button. The whole code it here:
http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~vladis2/LD23.zip maybe you can find the bug, even that I'm pretty sure it is something about premitions, but I did sign it and it works fine until I'm trying to open the file from the jar.

If you want to compile it your self you will need the externals:
http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~vladis2/lwjgl.rar

So what is causing the applet to crush?

Please help as quick as possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a File to read files from a Jar, you need to use an inputstream, hence the failure.

Comment: I still have problems when using JFileChooser.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272529/using-jfilechooser-with-lwjgl-applet-turns-not-responding